# Sending email Via SMTP with STARTTLS command with cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, ssl, smtp

I have been asked to use an external SMTP server with the following instructions:

"We expect you to connect to port 25 in cleartext, then issue a STARTTLS to commence TLS/SSL. Then log in"

Is this possible and if so, how should I do it?  As I understand it, this is different to setting the TLS to true in the smtp connection array, is that right?

UPDATE
Plodding towards victory here.  Looking at the code in SmtpTransport.php I can see it matches up with the spec linked in the comments (obviously) but the block 102-107 seems to set the host to either client or localhost - I'm setting the remote ip in the host configuration. Am i doing it wrong?

Cakes code:

```
protected function _connect() {
    $this->_generateSocket();
    if (!$this->_socket->connect()) {
        throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'Unable to connect to SMTP server.'));
    }
    $this->_smtpSend(null, '220');

    if (isset($this->_config['client'])) {
        $host = $this->_config['client'];
    } elseif ($httpHost = env('HTTP_HOST')) {
        list($host) = explode(':', $httpHost);
    } else {
        $host = 'localhost';
    }

    try {
        $this->_smtpSend("EHLO {$host}", '250');
        if ($this->_config['tls']) {
            $this->_smtpSend("STARTTLS", '220');
            $this->_socket->enableCrypto('tls');
            $this->_smtpSend("EHLO {$host}", '250');
        }
    } catch (SocketException $e) {
        if ($this->_config['tls']) {
            throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'SMTP server did not accept the connection or trying to connect to non TLS SMTP server using TLS.'));
        }
        try {
            $this->_smtpSend("HELO {$host}", '250');
        } catch (SocketException $e2) {
            throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'SMTP server did not accept the connection.'));
        }
    }
}
```

My Email Config:

```
    public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('me@example.com' => 'my name'),
    'host' => 'secretipaddress',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'me@example.com',
    'password' => 'secretpassword',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => true,
    'tls' => true
);
```

Comment: Sounds like someone who doesn't know about email explaining email - [ref](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3207#section-5) does it "just work" setting tls to true? SMTP is a standard protocol, nobody is likely to implement a none-standard permutation of it.

Comment: No it doesn't.  But it sounds like it is probably something else like a firewall issue & once thats fixed it might work setting tls to true.  Ill try some more & report back : )  thanks andy.

Comment: ps, thanks for link, amazing how reading the manual makes things clearer.

Comment: =) You might find it useful to use any mail client (apple mail, thunderbird, gmail, etc.) to send a test mail and in the process confirm the right settings.

Comment: update the Q with a bit more thinking & detail

Comment: ps.  Not possible to test using a mail client as its all firewalled up and only available to the servers ip address.  I can now telnet the smtp from the server and get a response, so that little obstacle has been overcome

Answer (score 0):

Enable the 'tls' to true in your config file app.php. 
It work for me and in cakephp 3.1 with gmail smtp